# JqGrid not displaying data MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

please check the jqgrid I am having, it just displays blank grid, my json is according to the expected format of grid. I am using jqGrid  4.4.4

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/GetData/',
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['CP', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'],
                colModel: [
                                { name: 'CP', index: 'CP', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'Val1', index: 'Val1', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'Val2', index: 'Val2', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'Val3', index: 'Val3', width: 150 }
                ],
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [5, 10, 15],
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'CP',
                viewrecords: true,

                sortorder: "asc",

                viewrecords: true,

                caption: "JSON Example"
            });
            $("#myGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });

        });

    </script>
```

My controller method looks like, where I am formatting data as per jqGrid documentation.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            List<Rate> myList = CallProcedure<Rate>("getVal").ToList();


            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = myList .Count,
                page = 1,
                records = 10,
                rows = (
                  from d in myList 
                  select new
                  {
                      id = d.CP,
                      cell = new string[] {
                      d.CP.ToString(),
                      d.Val1.ToString(),
                      d.Val2.ToString(),
                      d.Val3.ToString()
                      }
                  }).ToArray()
            };



            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Tried with setting jsonReader in the grid but still no success, can you please point where I am going wrong here? Thanks in advance

Json look like below

```
   {
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 25,
    "rows": [{
        "id": "AUSD",
        "cell": ["AUSD    ", "0.000000", "0.72315000", "0.000000"]
    }, {
        "id": "PPFF",
        "cell": ["PPFF    ", "0.000000", "1.10288000", "0.000000"]
    }, {
        "id": "XTYU",
        "cell": ["XTYU    ", "0.000000", "1.41479000", "0.000000"]
    }, {
        "id": "NUSD",
        "cell": ["NUSD    ", "-0.000020", "0.67097000", "-0.000020"]
    }, {
        "id": "USED",
        "cell": ["USED    ", "0.000000", "3.67278000", "0.000000"]
    }, {
        "id": "UAD",
        "cell": ["UAD    ", "0.000120", "1.37037000", "0.000020"]
    }]
}
```

New json look like,

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 25,
    "rows": [
        ["Val1    ", "0.000000", "0.72315000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val12    ", "0.000000", "1.10288000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val13    ", "0.000000", "1.41479000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val14    ", "-0.000020", "0.67097000", "-0.000020"],
        ["Val15    ", "0.000000", "3.67278000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val16    ", "0.000120", "1.37037000", "0.000020"],
        ["Val17    ", "0.000000", "0.99843000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val18    ", "0.000000", "24.53100000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val19    ", "0.000000", "6.76500000", "0.000000"],
        ["Val23    ", "0.000000", "7.77250000", "0.000000"]

    ]
}
```

Still the grid is blank :(

Update action method to return json in different format,

```
{
    "total": 25,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 10,
    "rows": [{
        "CP": "ADRR",
        "Val1": "0.000000",
        "Val2": "0.72315000",
        "Val3": "0.000000"
    }, {
        "CP": "TRRT",
        "Val1": "0.000000",
        "Val2": "1.10288000",
        "Val3": "0.000000"
    }, {
        "CP": "TRER",
        "Val1": "0.000000",
        "Val2": "1.41479000",
        "Val3": "0.000000"
    }]
}
```

The difference in the json is it contains " for "CP", "Val1" names. And the grid is still blank

What's wrong here? The breakpoint comes here when the page loads, it treturns the json as expected,

```
    public JsonResult GetData()
            {
                List<Live> dd = CallProc<Live>("getLiveData").ToList();


                var jsonData = new
                {
                    total = 1,
                    page = 1,
                    records = dd.Count,
                    rows = (
                      from d in dd
                      select new string[]
                      {
                          CP = d.CP.ToString(),
CP1 = d.CP1.ToString(),
                           CP2 = d.CP2.ToString(),
Cp3 =                           d.Cp3.ToString()
                      }).ToArray()

                };


                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonData); //just to check what json I am getting

                return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest in my comment is that:

```
  {
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"records": 25,
"rows": [["AUSD    ", "0.000000", "0.72315000", "0.000000"], 
         ["2", "PPFF    ", "0.000000", "1.10288000", "0.000000"],
         ["XTYU    ", "0.000000", "1.41479000", "0.000000"]
```

]
}

I alreay get issues with multiple grid regarding JSON result and it solved them.

Comment: updated json to have the format suggested by you, but the grid is still blank. Can't find whats going wring here

Comment: I suggest to test an example and inspect in the debugger the JSON result. It can help.

Comment: But sorry for that, I don't have more ideas about that, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

JqGrid does not accept any json in rows it needs the json formatted in name values pairs which matches the name field in column model.

[Here JsFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/106/)

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 25,
    "rows": [
        {CP: "Val1    ", Val1: "0.000000", Val2:"0.72315000", Val3: "0.000000"},
        {CP: "Val12    ",Val1: "0.000000", Val2: "1.10288000",Val3: "0.000000"},
        .....

    ]
}
```

To get that json you need to update your action method as follows

```
 public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            List<Rate> myList = CallProcedure<Rate>("getVal").ToList();


            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = myList .Count,
                page = 1,
                records = 10,
                rows = (
                  from d in myList 
                  select new
                  {
                     id = d.CP,
                     CP = d.CP.ToString(),
                     Val1= d.Val1.ToString(),
                     Val2 = d.Val2.ToString(),
                     Val3=  d.Val3.ToString()
                  }).ToArray()
            };



            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the input, updated code accordingly, please check the question for the updated json I am getting, but still the grid is blank

Comment: I don't see a reason on why your code won't work. Did you make sure the url in the grid is correct and is getting the data correctly? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/106/) is a sample I created for you using local data and it works.

Comment: with local data it is working. But with Url the grid is blank. Yes the url is correct, it is going there and it returns the json also but can't figure out what's going wrong here

Comment: please see the question updated, added action method, can you point where it's going wrong?

Comment: finally solved!!! The issue was, there was an AuthPrivilege attribute on controller level, which was preventing that json to be returned. Thanks to all

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too. because there is no way the data could not display if it is formatted the right way.

Comment: Me too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the result from the server in debugger ?
Is there any issue show in the console ?

If not, may be try to remove "ToArray()" in the jsonData block.

```
            var jsonData = new
        {
            total = myList .Count,
            page = 1,
            records = 10,
            rows = (
              from d in myList 
              select new
              {
                  id = d.CP,
                  cell = new string[] {
                  d.CP.ToString(),
                  d.Val1.ToString(),
                  d.Val2.ToString(),
                  d.Val3.ToString()
                  }
              })
        };
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. There is no error in console and removing ToArray() also didn't helped.

Comment: It is hitting the controller and json is also returned but somehow the grid is not loading data

Comment: I have updated question to show the json I am getting

Comment: Try to just return data in json. It's may be because of the structure inside your JSON. Remove id and cell and keep the array of data.