# Load JQGRID on AJAX success with dynamic columns and model

Tags: json, dynamic, jqgrid, load

i have done more than enough research in this but still a mystery.
i pulled table schema from server to create columns(`result.colNames`) and model(`result.colModel`) that work fine.

on same result,i am pulling table data(`result.colD`) to populate into JQgrid on success.

Grid is creating fine on success but data is not loading into it.

here are the code and screenshots.

i have spent lot of time in this, then posting here..hope this will be resolved here.

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "webapi/do/pullSchema/"+display,
                   data: "",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(result)
                   {

                        colD = JSON.stringify(result.colData); 
                        colN = result.colNames;
                        colM = result.colModel;

                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({ 
                            data:JSON.parse(colD),datatype: "local",
                            colNames:colN,  colModel :colM,
                            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                            rowNum: 5,
                            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                            viewrecords: true,
                            caption: 'DAta from table',
                            loadtext:'Loading, please wait'});


                   },
                   error: function(x, e)
                   {
                        alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);   
                   }
                });
```

below is sample data sets:

```
[dbname=null, tables=null, ColNames=[Plan_code, LOB], 
colModel=[{name:'Plan_code',index:'Plan_code',width:255}, {name:'LOB',index:'LOB',width:255}], colData=[{LOB=N, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=P, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=B, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82IRA}, {LOB=R, Plan_code=C82IRA}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with colData not being in a format jqgrid expects it's json(This is a common mistake many jqgrid developers make)

See the Question in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37572047/3038042) for details.

So in your case the fix would be to manipulate colData and create the right json.

```
colRows=[{LOB=N, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=P, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=B, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82IRA}, {LOB=R, Plan_code=C82IRA}]

colData = {
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"records": colRows.count,
rows:[{LOB=N, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=P, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=B, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82ACC}, {LOB=I, Plan_code=C82IRA}, {LOB=R, Plan_code=C82IRA}]
}



 Send this to jqgrid and then it will know how to display it.
```

Comment: length of column <> MODEL => {name:"Plan_code",index:"Plan_code",width:255},{name:"LOB",index:"LOB",width:255}
JSONStringify => ["{name:\"Plan_code\",index:\"Plan_code\",width:255}","{name:\"LOB\",index:\"LOB\",width:255}"]
parseJSON =>{name:"Plan_code",index:"Plan_code",width:255},{name:"LOB",index:"LOB",width:255}

COLUMN NAMES 

columns => Plan_code,LOB
JSON Stringify => ["Plan_code","LOB"]
parseJSON =>Plan_code,LOB

hardcoding below, working fine 

//colNames:["Plan_code", "LOB"], 
//colModel:[{name:"Plan_code",index:"Plan_code",width:255}, {name:"LOB",index:"LOB",width:255}],

Comment: sorry, i was not sure how to post my next big explaination , so types like this..

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved:

used below functions to create dynamic Column header and column Model.     function getColNames(data) {
        var keys = [];
        for(var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        }

```
    return keys;
}

function  getColModels(data) {
    var colNames= getColNames(data);
    var colModelsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {
        var str;
        if (i === 0) {
            str = {
                name: colNames[i],
                index:colNames[i],
                key:true,
                editable:true
            };
        } else {
            str = {
                name: colNames[i],
                index:colNames[i],
                editable:true
            };
        }
        colModelsArray.push(str);
    }

    return colModelsArray;
}
```