# Why my jqgrid not work in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and want to show user `gridview` for that purpose use `JqGrid`, in view page write this `ajax` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid(
            {
                url: '/POS/GetTableData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['First Name', 'Last Name'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'EmloyeeId', index: 'EmloyeeId', width: 150, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 150 }
                ], rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'EmloyeeId',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "List Employee Details",
                scrollOffset: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and in controller write this:

```
DataTable mytTable = new DataTable();
            mytTable.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
            mytTable.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
            mytTable.Rows.Add("behzad", "razzaqi");
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mytTable);
```

But not show me any data!,How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: Datatable given column name should same as jqGrid colModel name

Comment: @SambathKumarS change that datatable column name to:EmloyeeId and FName but so not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JqGrid does not accept any json in rows it needs the json formatted in name value pairs which matches the name field in column model.

See the the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572047/jqgrid-not-displaying-data-mvc/37596710#37596710)  for more details and the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data) for how the json data should look.

So the solution for you will be to change the grid code as follows
add LName column model to hold the lastname

```
script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid(
            {
                url: '/POS/GetTableData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['First Name', 'Last Name'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'EmloyeeId', index: 'EmloyeeId', width: 150, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 150 },
                { name: 'LName', index: 'LName', width: 150 }
                ], rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'EmloyeeId',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "List Employee Details",
                scrollOffset: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In your controller change your code as follows

```
       public JsonResult GetTableData()
    {
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 20,
            page = 1,
            records = 2,
            rows = new[] {

              new{
                  EmloyeeId = 1,
                  FName = "behzad",
                  LName = "razzaqi"
              },

               new {
                      EmloyeeId = 2,
                    FName = "robert",
                    LName = "john"
                }
               }

        };

        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

Comment: Correct suggestion! One should use `return Json(jsonData);`  in MVC application instead of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. I would only use `loadonce: true` scenario and to change the server code to return the array of items (`new[] ...`) only. One should add `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` (in case of usage [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)), remove unneeded `index`, `width: 150` and `stype: 'text'` properties from `colModel` and to replace `scrollOffset: 0` to `height: "auto"` and add `autoencode: true`. One should add `gridview: true` if old jqGrid is used.

Comment: One small comment to my previous comment: the client part uses `sortname: 'EmloyeeId', sortorder: "desc"`, but the server returns not correctly sorted data (one have to sort on the server side based on `sortname` and `sortorder` options, which will be send to the server as `sidx` and `sord`). One can sort the data on the client side in free jqGrid fork if both `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` options are specified.

Comment: @behibehi did you try the solution?